# Do Celebrity Big Brother contestants still earn a fee if they are ejected from the show?

Tags: big-brother

The UK version of CBB has had two housemates ejected on behavioral grounds within the first few days...

One of these contestants, Ken Morley, talked about deliberately being rude and irritable so he would be voted out quicker by the public, and take his fee for only being in the house a small amount of time.

This tactic backfired, however, as some of his behavior was considered to be racist, and he was forced to leave.

Will he still be paid?

Comment: Are you planning to join the "cast" and employ this tactic? Otherwise, why would anyone care?

Comment: His question is legit! I've been wondering about that to! @wbogacz

Comment: *considered to be racist*. He was about as racist as you can get! Hope they don't pay him a penny.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, the first Celebrity (Jeremy Jackson) to be kicked out by the producers of the Show appeared on the chat show *This Morning* to defend his actions in an interview...

During this interview, he was asked directly by Phillip Schofield if celebrities that are kicked out in such a manner still get paid. His response was revealing...

> Jeremy: "There are ongoing investigations. But if you lose your mind
>   in there and hit someone, sure you'll not get anything..."

He indicated that there is a precedent for stars to receive their fee (or at least part of it), depending on the severity and circumstances of ejection.

He also stated he is likely to get paid, but this [will be a lesser amount](http://www.mirror.co.uk/3am/celebrity-news/jeremy-jacksons-first-tv-appearance-4970492) than expected...

> Before the interview kicked off, Phillip told viewers Jeremy wanted to
>   point out that he’s not being paid for this interview, and when asked
>   whether he will get paid for his time on the show he said he’s “a
>   victim to what they chose to give me” and there is a lengthy contract.